# Getting fix-broken-install and can't install anything (CUDA libs)

Tags: apt, nvidia, cuda

I have attempted to install Sox with `apt-get install sox`, and I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 nvidia-cuda-toolkit : Depends: nvidia-cuda-dev (= 9.1.85-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 sox : Depends: libsox-fmt-alsa (= 14.4.2-3ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libsox-fmt-ao (= 14.4.2-3ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libsox-fmt-oss (= 14.4.2-3ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libsox-fmt-pulse (= 14.4.2-3ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsox-fmt-base (= 14.4.2-3ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsox3 (= 14.4.2-3ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have seen this type of error discussed quite a bit, and I'm pretty sure in my case it's caused by a faulty nvidia install. Running `apt --fix-broken install` as suggested gives me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libnvidia-common-440 libnvidia-extra-440
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nvidia-cuda-dev
Recommended packages:
  libnvcuvid1
The following NEW packages will be installed
  nvidia-cuda-dev
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 431 not to upgrade.
48 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/263 MB of archives.
After this operation, 734 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

But when I continue it gives:

```
(Reading database ... 196302 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-cuda-dev (9.1.85-3ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/cublas.h', which is also in package libcublas-dev 10.2.2.89-1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Currently I am unable to install anything, even using the desktop. I have two Titan RTX cards, and run TensorFlow, which I installed according to the instructions on the TensorFlow site [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#ubuntu_1804_cuda_110) (although I used CUDA 10.1). But I suspect (I can't really remember) I initially installed `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` using apt, and then forgot about it. I do recall having some issues with the install, but the cards have worked so far without problem.

From searching I came up with this as [a possible best answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1132098):

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install -f
```

Or [possibly](https://askubuntu.com/a/1198355):

```
dpkg -P nvidia-cuda-toolkit nvidia-cuda-dev
apt --fix-broken install
```

But I wanted to check before running this command. It looks like the root of the problem is the absence of `nvidia-cuda-dev`, and indeed when I run

```
apt list --installed | grep nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

it locates the toolkit, but the same with `nvidia-cuda-dev` fails to find anything. So I guess I just need to remove `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` (but do I need it?).

Comment: In your output: `dpkg: error processing archive A.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite 'File_B', which is also in package C`. A and C *conflict*. You have two choices: 1) Uninstall C in order to install A, or 2) Look up the manpage to learn how to use the apt `--force` flag properly so you don't cause damage.

Comment: Thanks very much. Given that I want to update the drivers and upgrade to CUDA 11, I am minded to just remove all CUDA/NVIDIA packages with `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda*` followed by `sudo apt remove --autoremove nvidia-cuda-toolkit` and `sudo apt remove --autoremove nvidia-*`.